# Is Flex trigger architecture recommended for Spark components?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am reading the book "Flash Builder 4 and Flex 4 Bible". On page 373 the following is mentioned:

> The older Flex 3 effects support an architecture known as a trigger, which plays an effect in reaction to a specific event. This code, for example, would cause an object to fade in and out in reaction to having its visible property set to true or false:
>
> ```
> <mx:Image source=”assets/flower1.jpg” 
> showEffect=”{myMXEffect}” hideEffect=”{myMXEffect}”/>
> ```
>
> If you try to use this syntax with Spark effects, the results are inconsistent. Adobe recommends that Spark
>   effects be called directly from ActionScript code or in the context of a view state transition.

I cannot however find any such thing mentioned in adobe documentation. Is it true that "If you try to use this syntax with Spark effects, the results are inconsistent." ?

Comment: I haven't heard of this before, but personally, I don't use the Adobe animation libs.  I use [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logged as a bug here titled "Spark Effects Do Not Work With Data Triggers on Components" here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-19743

basically :

```
<FxTextArea id="textArea" showEffect="myHaloFade"/> <!-- Fade -->
works! But:
<FxTextArea id="textArea" showEffect="myGumboFade"/> <!-- FxFade -->
Does not.
```

You can track the progress there.

I also found an offical adobe wiki specifically mentioning this : http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/New+Effects+for+Components+and+Graphics

> Note that triggers do not currently work on the new effects. We should come back to this later to determine whether to retrofit triggers onto these new classes or leave Triggers behind for older components and effects.